# css hover only working in firefox

Tags: html, css, hover

Trying to spin a image with css, but for some reason `hover` only works for firefox. The image spin in all browser but the `hover` spin doesn't work in IE and chrome

```
.button img {
        position:absolute;
        left:500px;
        top:300px;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        -webkit-animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
        animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
    }

    .button img:hover{
        -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    }


    @-moz-keyframes rotation { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @keyframes rotation { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the why part yet (looking for it) but I've observed that `.button:hover` instead of `.button img:hover` works fine on chrome.

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaranjan/AfdRd/1/) here (with rest of the code same) and it works on chrome.